# Blackberry web services for 10.3 os

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, qnetworkrequest

I am developing a BlackBerry 10 apps with Cascades (C++ programming language) right now. Can anyone tell me how do i make a call to an web service in BlackBerry 10: Cascades? I'm just a beginner, so i don't really know anything. Thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what your requirement is, but since you are a beginner it is probably best to start small. Have you looked at the WebView Cascades control?

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__webview.html

Comment: i want to make use of the API so for tht i want the code for the login page

Answer (score 0):

How about [XmlDataAccess](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__data__xmldataaccess.html) and [JsonDataAccess](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__data__jsondataaccess.html), you can find samples in the documentation.

Comment: i already have the API with me i just want to implement it so i just want the source code for it and how to use that API

Comment: There are examples in documentation how to use those classes. Is your API XML or JSON?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of samples on github.

[samples](https://github.com/blackberry/)

There is also a sample project using QtSoap to access web services.

[soapxml](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/soapxml)